# WSGI module and Django settings locations

Tags: python, django, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm using Django with uWSGI and trying to organise my web server config files as follow:

```
/proj/
    web_config/
        docker-compose.py
        ...
        prod/
            nginx.conf
            wsgi.py
            uwsgi_params
            uwsgi.ini
            ...
    app/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
```

My problem is I don't know how to reference the final django settings module from my WSGI module:

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
# ...    
module = wsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=(../../)app.settings # <- Problem here
```

**wsgi.py**

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#                                               v- Or problem here -v
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "(../../)app.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Is there a way to point to the right `app.settings`
without placing `wsgi.py` in `/proj/` or `/proj/app` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, to reference to django settings, all you need to do is chdir from your `uwsgi.ini` to `/proj/` directory. Now load your `wsgi.py` file (you can keep it in your `app/` subdirectory, it doesn't contain any settings) from it using `module` uWSGI setting and set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `app.settings`, without anything else (it is enough to set it only in `wsgi.py` file).

It should look like this (if you've moved your `wsgi.py` back to `app/`):

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
# ...
chdir = /proj/
module = app.wsgi
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you don't want (for some reason) to keep your `wsgi.py` file in `app/`, your `uwsgi.py` should have:

```
[uwsgi]
# ...
chdir = /proj/
module = web_config.prod.wsgi
```

But `web_config` and `prod` should be proper python modules (in python 2 they must have `__init__.py` file inside). Content of `wsgi.py` doesn't change.

Comment: I see, that seems logical. Good explanation. I think I'll put my WSGI module  in the root level then.